# how to open modal in parent window if accessed from an iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have a page where the data has been shown directly on the page and I have an iframe on the page where I have the below Modal link.
Modal is opening in the iframe, but i want to open it on the parent window i tried `target="_parent"` & `target="_top"` but i can not access it on the parent window.

Iframe in the parent page:

```
<iframe src="milk.php" style="width: 100%; border: 0;" target="_parent" ></iframe>
```

**Link inside iframe**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#cpartCode<?php print $month; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini"
target="_top">View Records</a>
```